# How can I configure two datacentres in master-slave topology

Tags: mariadb, galera, maxscale

I am trying to insert  data between two datacenters using mariadb, galera and maxscale.
each data centre has three nodes, one as master and other two as slave. Now I want my data to be inserted to second data centre in case if my 1st datacentre fails.My requirement is to configure master node of datacentre1(DC1) as slave to master node of second datacentre(DC2).
What configuration should I do in maxscale to achieve it.Any link will be helpful.

Thanks